# Want to know the consequences of making out=null instead of out.close(). Out is instance of FileoutputStream

Tags: java, file, io

I want to know the consequences of making output stream null instead of closing it. If i do out=null, will this cause resource leak?

Comment: Depends on the type of `OutputStream`.

Comment: @Sotiros Delimanolis It is FileOutputStream

Comment: You can't. You can only make a reference to an output strem null.

Comment: Have a look at any finalizers the OutputStream class you're using may provide. What's in there is what ultimately happens when the object gets collected. Usually, the stream should be closed there as a last resort. Don't rely on it though, or you're asking for trouble sooner or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If i do `outputStream = null`, will this cause resource leak?

Probably yes, though it depends on what the stream is (ultimately) connected to.

The other question is whether it matters.  That also depends ...

- If the stream includes a buffer in the output pipeline, then assigning `null` instead of closing could result in loss of buffered data.
- If you do this repeatedly, the leaked resources could build up, ultimately leading to your application failing because it has run out of "file descriptors".
- On the other hand, if you leak resources *slowly*, it is possible that the streams will be garbage collected and finalized before the "file descriptor" shortage bites.  (The `finalize()` method calls `close()` ...)

But either way, it is *best practice* to call `close()` ... and to make sure that the close *always* happens by using "try / finally" or "try with resources".  Assigning `null` instead of calling `close()` is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Always `close` your streams.

`Stream` is not only a normal object on heap like normal java `object`, It deals  with underlying operating system for writing.

Then flush won't happen, If  you make your reference `null`

See the docs of close

> Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be written out. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an indication that, if any bytes previously written have been buffered by the implementation of the output stream, such bytes should immediately be written to their intended destination.

So what about the above procedure If you simply make the `reference` simply `null` ?

**Your question won't raise from jdk7**

If you are using java7  ,that is [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) ,then you will never have to close streams explicitly.

Comment: @suresh atta We use Java JDK 1.5.0_22. Is there any equivalent of try-with-resources statement prior to jdk7?

Comment: @ravikuwi No No. It is introduced in Jdk 1.7. For below versions you have call `close()`. One thing I would like to ask, what is wrong with calling close() ??

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the implementation of the outputStream, it is hard to answer your question.  But remember, when you are setting a variable to null, you are not eliminating the object that the variable originally pointed to.  Setting something to null is not equivalent to calling delete say in C++, or release in Objective-C.  There is no cleanup code that is automatically called.  That is exactly the reason that close() exists in the first place.  You can assume that since it exists, it is there to be used to do exactly what it says - cleanup resources.

In short the answer is yes, that will likely leak resources.  Call the methods that were intended to be called for cleanup!

Answer (score 0):

By jsut setting the reference to `null` you don't release the underlying file handle. This means you depend on the garbage collector and finalization to do this, which might very well cause runtime errors because the OS runs out of file handles if the finalization can't keep up. Also, it is not determined when the contents you wrote to the stream will make it to the disk.